# Vue-Router breaks when reloading page with laravel-6

Tags: laravel, vue.js, browser, routes, refresh

**What is actually happening?**
If I refresh my web browser than doesn’t recognize anymore my route

Comment: What do you mean of doesn't recognize ?

Comment: Did you used routes history ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 I mean don not show anythings in my **pages show not found**, Yes I used **history**

Comment: did you put already a route that will catch your currect url when reload ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use route history, like this

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
});
```

Everything that is not matched in previous routes will be served by the AppController, which returns the naked view that contains the files for bootstrapping the VueJS application. In your web routes put this one on the bottom of all your routes

```
 Route::get('/{path}', 'AppController@index')->where( 'path', "([A-z\d\-/_.]+)?" );
```

see this article [catch routes](https://mauricius.dev/laravel-catch-all-route-for-vue-single-page-applications/)